# Find pattern in akka stream

Tags: scala, stream

In my scala code I have an akka stream (Source[ByteString, Long]) and i search a pattern (e.g "aabb") in this stream, and if exist the position.

It is possible?

The stream consist in genomic sequences(from 20 to 64Mb). If the sequences contains a pattern of 32 nucleobases then maybe this sequence it is interesting and i save it with the position with first occurance, otherwise waste.
If used inputstream i can create a bytebuffer of 32bytes and check the sequence in bytebuffer. With akka stream there is another mode to done it

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: You can use `Source.zipWithIndex` to get the position, and `Source.sliding` to get a sliding window on the stream which you can use to match the pattern.

Comment: @devkat -- unfortunately I think that won't work. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

It will be tricky, because the byte pattern might span two `ByteString`s in the stream.

If you are sure that all messages will fit in memory, the easiest approach will be to aggregate the stream into a single byte string and search in that.

It is possible without aggregating the stream into a single string, but I don't think it's built in. The `akka.http.scaladsl.unmarshalling.MultipartUnmarshallers` code in Akka HTTP shows how you can do this in a streaming manner, but it's very fiddly. (Akka pipes the stream through a `akka.http.impl.engine.parsing.BodyPartParser` state machine.)

#### Question needs clarification

What is your use-case?

Most Reactive Streams are consume-once, so what are you planning to do with the index anyway?

If you are trying to parse MIME boundaries in an HTTP entity, then use Akka's MultipartUnmarshallers code directly.